# Adding Jar file in Flex mobile app

Tags: apache-flex, jar

How to include Jar file in Flex mobile app. I want to add .jar file as a library in flex app. In flex projects there is an option to add only SWC file. how can we add .jar file as a library file in a flex mobile application.

Thank you.

Comment: what have you tryed so far? Show us some effort and come up with a concreate error.

Comment: Including it is one thing.  Using code inside a JAR it is something entirely different.  Can you please elaborate on what you want to do?

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply. I want to import the JAR file as a external library in Flex Mobile project. Is there any way to do this?